# get_the_ID() retrieves same ID on Gutenberg's Query Loop

Tags: custom-field, loop, shortcode, query-posts

I'm using Gutenberg editor and I want to add a shortcode (using XYZ PHP Code) that uses the post id to retrieve certain ACF value.

I'm editing the **home page** where the last blog posts are shown, but I can't find a way to get the `post_id` of each item on the loop. I'm using this on the XYZ Shortcode:

```
<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>
```

It always displays **the same post_id**, the one that belongs to the **first post** that gets displayed on the list.

How can I get the ID for each item on the loop?

[image]

I am missing something here?

Comment: If you're inside a custom loop, you might need to globalize the post object.

Comment: @ray-happyforms So... is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: @ray-happyforms not sure what you mean by "custom loop". This is the default loop created by TwentyTwentyThree theme when using Gutenberg editor.

Comment: @Alvaro, did my answer help, and more importantly, can you let us know how did you solve the issue? 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you did nothing wrong.**

[It's a known issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/43053) and in WordPress v6.1.3 and up to the current stable release as of writing (v6.2.2), it's happening because of the following [lines](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2.2/src/wp-includes/block-template.php#L241-L242) in [`get_the_block_template_html()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_block_template_html/) which returns the markup for the current (block-based) template:

```php
$content = do_shortcode( $content );
$content = do_blocks( $content );
```

So as you could see, *shortcodes in the post content (`post_content`) are being run **before** the blocks are parsed*, which means that by the time your shortcode runs, the Query Loop block has not yet run, hence `get_the_ID()`, `get_post()->ID`, etc. would return the ID of the first post or whatever is the current post in the current loop.

In the past, it used to be that [`do_blocks()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_blocks/) is being called before [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/), then in WordPress v6.1.2, the `do_shortcode()` call was removed and yet, added back in v6.1.3 (see changesets [55771](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/55771/branches/6.1/src/wp-includes/block-template.php) and [55830](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/55830/branches/6.1/src/wp-includes/block-template.php) in Trac), so I don't know if it will ever be back to any of that behaviors.

Nonetheless, there are 2 possible workarounds you can try:

- In your shortcode function, return a special tag like `%xyz_shortcode%`, and use a filter hook like [`render_block`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block/) or [`render_block_<name>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block_this-name/) to replace that tag with the "real" content.

  See example [here](https://github.com/5ally/xyz-block-demos/blob/trunk/class-xyz-shortcode.php).
- Create or turn your shortcode into a [*dynamic* block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/), i.e. a block type with a `render_callback`.

  See examples [here](https://github.com/5ally/xyz-block-demos/blob/trunk/src).

  Note that I'm consuming a [block context](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-context/) named `postId` which gives us the correct ID of the current post in the Query Loop. See [`xyz-block-csr/index.jsx`](https://github.com/5ally/xyz-block-demos/blob/trunk/src/xyz-block-csr/index.jsx) and [`xyz-block-ssr/index.jsx`](https://github.com/5ally/xyz-block-demos/blob/trunk/src/xyz-block-ssr/index.jsx) to see how I used that context.